# What is difference between SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site; and SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)

Tags: spsite

What is difference between

```
SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;

 and

 SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)
```

Which is good practice?

Answer (score 3):

`SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)` creates a new instance of the `SPSite` object, and you are responsible to dispose it. However, you don't need to dispose `SPSite` in `SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;`

Comment: I think its best never to dispose SPContext.Current.Site, because other objects might use it.

Comment: That is what I have written :-)

Comment: a part of it.. you say you don't need..  ;-)

Comment: So I have to use USING block for case 1

Comment: or a Try/Catch/Finally, which is what USING gets converted to (well, Try/Finally).

Answer (score 0):

Well the first on uses the already existing site in the SPContext object.

The second one initiate a new SPSite object (from the url of the current site).

The second one should primarily be used when you use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. That is because otherwise the site object will not be elevated.

Also, the second one is used when working with another site then the current (by passing in GUID or Url)